# Reading ResultSet: java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, resultset, sqlexception

I'm trying to get information from a MySQL database. I can connect and do things such as insert data into tables fine, and although I receive a `ResultSet`, I can't read it. Here's my code:

```
public ResultSet executeQuery(String query) {
    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    try {
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

        if (stmt.execute(query)) {
            rs = stmt.getResultSet();
        }
        return rs;
    }
    catch (SQLException ex){
        System.err.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
        System.err.println("SQLState: " + ex.getSQLState());
        System.err.println("VendorError: " + ex.getErrorCode());
    }
    finally {
        if (stmt != null) {
            try {
                stmt.close();
            } catch (SQLException sqlEx) { } // ignore

            stmt = null;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Trying to read the `ResultSet`:

```
ResultSet set = executeQuery("SELECT rank FROM players");
try {
    while(set.next()) {
          System.out.println(set.getInt("rank") + "");
    }
} catch(Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        set.close();
    } catch (SQLException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I get this error:

> java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed

I've been looking around the internet and on different forums all day. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, you're closing it every time in your finally statement

Answer (score 0):

Your finally block in executeQuery closes your statement before you've iterated over the results.

Answer (score 0):

### **TL;DR Your `executeQuery` closes the `Statement`.**

From the [JavaDoc for `Statement.close`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#close())

> Releases this Statement object's database and JDBC resources
>   immediately instead of waiting for this to happen when it is
>   automatically closed.

You `close()` your `Statement` *before* you read your `ResultSet`. Closing a `Statement` causes all of the `ResultSet` instances associate with that `Statement` to also be closed.

You need to pass in a [`Consumer<ResultSet>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html) into a different method, and process the `ResultSet` whilst the `Statement` is open:

```
public void executeQuery(final String query, final Consumer<ResultSet> consumer) {
    try(final Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        final ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query)) {
            consumer.accept(rs);
    }
    catch (SQLException ex){
        System.err.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
        System.err.println("SQLState: " + ex.getSQLState());
        System.err.println("VendorError: " + ex.getErrorCode());
    }
}
```

I have also fixed your code:

1. I have replaced your `try..finally` with a `try-with-resources`
2. You execute your query **twice** by calling `stmt.executeQuery(query)` and then `stmt.execute(query)`. This is not only wasteful, but you lose the reference to the first `ResultSet` and if `Statement.close` didn't close all the associated resultsets you would have had a memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

Well, two things -

1) I do not get why you have both execute() and executeQuery() in your method? I think executeQuery() should work for you.

2) Do not close the statement before iterating through resultset. Make it an instance variable and close it after iterating.